# The system cannot find the file specified? Using R Studio from Anaconda (Python.exe)

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rstudio

I'm currently training data in RStudio and this error message was thrown:

```
path[1]="D:\Anaconda3\envs\rstudio/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified2020-12-01 10:56:44.908067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
```

It seems that Python.exe isn't located? Can anyone guide me as to how I can resolve this? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same problem as python.exe isn't in the specified folder.

Comment: @Comte, I was able to find the solution from a github forum. I'll provide the link: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/834

Comment: Really appreciate you getting back to me. I actually resolved this by copying the current version of a python.exe from another folder in the anaconda folder and dropping it in the path above. Before attempting what the github suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that most likely because your string contains both \ and / it doesn't resolve the path correctly, although it is of course hard to say for sure without any surrounding code or usage of it.

Comment: Hi @Tarranoth ! This isn't a code, this was the actual error message. It might be an environment issue buy I'm not sure.